# Python : Dynamic game board

Tags: python

Hello so i need to draw a game board with dynamic width and height:

format:

```
  ----   ----   ----
|  01  |  02  |  03  |
  ----   ----   ----
|  04  |  05  |  06  |
  ----   ----   ---- 
|  07  |  08  |  09  |
  ----   ----   ----
Enter width and height (min = 2x2, max 6x8):
```

This is what i got now:

```
def board_draw(height, width):
    for x in range(height):
        print(" --- " * width)
        print("|   |" * width)
    print(" --- " * width)

heightinp= int(input("Enter the height of the board: "))
widthinp= int(input("Enter the width of the board: "))

board_draw(heightinp,widthinp)
```

Could someone help me with printing the numbers inside i cant get it to work..

Comment: It isn’t drawing the boxes correctly, either.

Comment: Read docs about `str.format`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str.format()` is a good choice for inserting numbers into those strings.
`str.join()` is a good choice for joining together a lot of strings. In your case, I'd use a generator expression inside the `.join()`.

```
def board_draw(height, width):
    for x in range(height):
        print("  ---- " * width)
        print("|" +
              "|".join('  {:02d}  '.format(x * width + y + 1)
                       for y in range(width)) +
              "|")
    print("  ---- " * width)
```

Result:

```
$ python3 x.py 
Enter the height of the board: 3
Enter the width of the board: 4
  ----   ----   ----   ---- 
|  01  |  02  |  03  |  04  |
  ----   ----   ----   ---- 
|  05  |  06  |  07  |  08  |
  ----   ----   ----   ---- 
|  09  |  10  |  11  |  12  |
  ----   ----   ----   ----
```

Just for fun, here is one that uses Unicode box-drawing characters. (Note: this is Python3 syntax).

```
def board_draw(height, width):
    top = "┌" + "┬".join(["─"*6]*width) + "┐\n"
    bottom = "└" + "┴".join(["─"*6]*width) + "┘"
    middle = "├" + "┼".join(["─"*6]*width) + "┤\n"
    print(top +
          middle.join(
              "│" +
              "│".join('  {:02d}  '.format(x * width + y + 1)
                       for y in range(width)) +
              "│\n"
              for x in range(height)) +
          bottom)
```

Result:

```
$ python3 x.py 
Enter the height of the board: 4
Enter the width of the board: 3
┌──────┬──────┬──────┐
│  01  │  02  │  03  │
├──────┼──────┼──────┤
│  04  │  05  │  06  │
├──────┼──────┼──────┤
│  07  │  08  │  09  │
├──────┼──────┼──────┤
│  10  │  11  │  12  │
└──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

Printing the numbers makes your grid dramatically more complicated. You'll have to rewrite your entire board draw function.

What you essentially want to do is:

1. Draw the top
2. For each row, draw a side, then a number, then a side as many times as there are squares, keeping track of what square was last.
3. Draw the bottom

Here's one possible implementation of what you want:

```
def board_draw(height, width):
    square = 0
    print(" --- " * width)
    for x in range(height):
        line = "| "
        for i in range(0, width):
            line += format(square, '02d') + " | "
            square += 1
        print(line)
    print(" --- " * width)    

heightinp= int(input("Enter the height of the board: "))
widthinp= int(input("Enter the width of the board: "))

board_draw(heightinp,widthinp)
```